# Easiest way to accomplish dual boot goal

Tags: windows, 12.04, dual-boot

Here's the situation: I've got a 64 bit dell inspiron 15 that currently dual boots ubuntu 11.10, and backtrack 5r2. I've backed up all the data I need on both of these operating systems, and heres what I want: Dual booting ubuntu 12.04 and windows 7 (sometime before next month so I can run diablo 3). I can make any changes to the system neccesary. If I do a clean install of 12.04 and then install windows wont windows overwrite grub and make my ubuntu partition unreachable? My friend told me I can't do windows first because "theres no such thing as a clean install for windows".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install windows first, it will over write GRUB otherwise.
Install 12.04 from within windows ( not within, from within). Use GPARTED to sort your final partitions sizes, file systems and mount points ( e.g. /Home; / ).
If you still want to run BT5r2 you can make a partition for it at this point or later.

Comment: Can I just install the windowser clean like that? It's competent enough to do that?

Comment: not sure - but would assume so

Answer (score 0):

I hope [this](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/22/how-to-dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-11-04) tutorial can help you.
Also [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125744/issue-with-dualboot-12-04-and-windows-7-with-w7-loader) post can help you.

My personal recommendation is install windows 7 first and go for ubuntu.
It wont give you any trouble.