# issue with dualboot 12.04 and windows 7 (with w7 loader)

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

i have windows 7 installed (i install it first because for me it was always easier to have dual boot working) and i want to install 12.04 (i've tried 11.10 and 11.04 and i have the same problem) but i can't make dual boot works.

When i install w7, the installer create an additional partition with the loader (i'm not sure what is in this partition because other installers didn't create it) so in sda1 is a small partition with the loader and in sda2 is the windows 7 partition.

when i try to install Ubuntu, i create a partition for the / directory, one for the /home and one for swap. After install Ubuntu grub never starts and w7 starts automatically.

i tried setting the sda1 (while i am installing Ubuntu) as the boot directory but grub didnt recognize w7 (and i couldn't add it to grub). After reinstall w7 and Ubuntu i tryg the clasic 'fix' for grub the windows 7 loader keeps but showing a message that it is broken (and that i must use the w7 disk to restore it).

i hope someone has a solution for this, i search a lot but i can't found a solution.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

When installing Windows 7 on empty disk it creates a small "System Reserved" boot partition and a bigger with Windows 7 proper.

You can install Ubuntu choosing to install its boot loader (GRUB2) to its partition instead of MBR. So it will not destroy Windows booting (and MBR).

Later to add Ubuntu to Windows boot menu create a "boot sector loader" and use "dd for Windows" to get a copy of Ubuntu partition boot record - see [here, Section 8](http://www.boyans.net/VBCD_HowTo.html) how to do this.

Comment: i try selecting the loader partition to install the boot loader but it doesnt work...  it still loads only w7.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. when planning for dual booting with windows and ubuntu, you should
   install the ubuntu GRUB loader in windows boot loader partition. if
   you fail to install the GRUB loader in windows partition,when you
   boot your pc windows 7 boot loader gets loaded.

   So you wont get a chance to load your ubuntu.Now you install the
   GRUB in windows boot loader partition. It wont affect anything.
2. If you dont like installing your ubuntu again, then go for [easyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).
   this is a tool which allows you to edit the Boot Configuration Data(BCD).
   So you can easily edit the boot configuration.
   Install EasyBCD on windows and I hope [this](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/22/how-to-dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-11-04/2/) tutorial can help you.
   I would recommend this one. Because its fastest and also easy to do.

Comment: i try selecting the loader partition to install the boot loader but it doesnt work... it still loads only w7.

Comment: can you post the screen shot of your easyBCD configuration?